# Простой способ объединения массивов строк

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Добрый день!

Мне нужно объединить два массива строкового типа, каким простым способом я могу сделать это?

```
String[] bothArray(String[] first, String[] second) {
    return ??;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если разрешено использовать *Java8*, то можно воспользоваться классом `Stream` и лямбдами:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

// . . .

String[] bothArray(final String[] first, final String[] second)
{
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), Stream.of(second)).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Компактно, красиво и не требует внешних компонентов.

Answer (score 10):

С помощью библиотеки [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29):

```
String[] both = (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

[отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80559/4953620)

---

Другой вариант

```
public static String[] combine(String[] a, String[] b){
    int length = a.length + b.length;
    String[] result = new String[length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
    return result;
}
```

[источник с примерами](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/combine-integer-and-string-array-java-example-tutorial.html)

---

Еще один вариант для всех типов. Тут можно не только примитивные типы использовать, а так же объектов

```
public <T> T[] concatenate (T[] a, T[] b) {
    int aLen = a.length;
    int bLen = b.length;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] c = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), aLen+bLen);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);

    return c;
}
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80503/4953620)

Answer (score 4):

И еще один вариант. (Редко вижу его упоминание)

```
String[] array;
StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();
for(String data: array){
   newStr.append(data);
}
return newStr.toString();
```

Comment: Старый добрый StringBuilder.

Comment: Да, не сравнится concat с StringBuilder. (Редко вижу его упоминание?) это как, в этой статье да.